# Executing custom Gradle task using scripts

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

How to write the task in the build.gradle which will execute this code:

```
**gradle hideSecret -Pkey=test123456 -PkeyName=YourSecretKeyName**
```

I use this lib: https://github.com/klaxit/hidden-secrets-gradle-plugin
and I want to make the hideSecrets automatically in pre build.

Smth like this:

```
task hideSecret {
    doLast {
        exec {
            workingDir "${rootDir}"
            commandLine "hideSecret -Pkey=${key} -PkeyName=${keyName}"
        }
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.getByName("preBuild").dependsOn("hideSecret")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to redefine the hideSecret task.  Just set the properties as you wish and configure the dependency:

```
afterEvaluate {
    project.ext.key = 'test123456'
    project.ext.keyName = 'YourSecretKeyName'
    tasks.getByName("preBuild").dependsOn("hideTask")
}
```

Comment: Great, but how to write the task properly with this command : hideSecret -Pkey=${key} -PkeyName=${keyName}?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a task with Exec type

```
task executeCMD(type:Exec) {
  workingDir '.'
  commandLine 'gradle', 'hideSecret', '-Pkey=test123456', '-PkeyName=YourSecretKeyName'
     doLast {
         println "Executed!"
     }
 }
```

OR you can use it with gradle project exec like this

```
 task executeCMD{
     doLast {
         exec {
             workingDir "."
             executable 'gradle'
             args 'hideSecret', '-Pkey=test123456'', '-PkeyName=YourSecretKeyName'
         }
         println "Executed!"
     }
 }
```

More information about excuting can be found at [gradle official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) .

Comment: Causes the error: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:executeCMD'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'build 'test-project'' 
 and this:
Cause: error=2, No such file or directory